# Get the count of a value for each row in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL question. Below is my data and query

```
select ID from table
```

---

```
ID

4   
4   
5   
3   
5   
3   
3
```

What query should I add to my select list so that it gives me the occurrence of a value for each specfic row(I do not want the total count, I want something like a rank of occurrence).

```
4 1--this is the first time we got a 4 in the list, so 1
4 2--this is the second time we got a 4 in the list, so 2
5 1--this is the first time we got a 5 in the list, so 1
3 1--this is the first time we got a 3 in the list, so 1
5 2--this is the second time we got a 5 in the list, so 2
3 2--this is the second time we got a 3 in the list, so 2
3 3--this is the third time we got a 3 in the list, so 3
```

Comment: might be similar to 
[mode calculation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223003/mode-calculation-without-a-subquery-field-in-mysql

Comment: That's for MySQL, I don't think any of that can help here. :( Steve has already nailed it.

Comment: It's not quite that simple.  `row_number()` is the right direction, but to match the expected output, the trick is to preserve the original row order.

Answer (score 2):

You want ROW_NUMBER():

```
SELECT 
    [Id],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Id] ORDER BY [Id])
FROM ...
```

You'll probably need to change the Order By clause to get the right output.

Comment: By itself, `row_number() over (partition by id order by id)` will not preserve the original row order.  If that matters, you would have to generate an order somehow.  Note that `row_number() over (partition by id order by (select 1))` also loses the original ordering.  (I am testing on SQL Server 2014 in 2012 compatibility.)

Comment: That's why I mentioned that the Order By clause would need to be changed. I'm guessing that there are other fields in the table that could be used to set the order.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul and Steve. I tried both row_number() and rank() but I messed up with the order by. SO, I was not able to get the results. Both the answers work for me.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a numbering from an order of rows, use `row_number()` or `rank()`.  The problem is, `row_number()` [does not guarantee the original order will be preserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810627/sql-server-2005-row-number-without-order-by).  You could try this:

```
select
    [id],
    row_number() over (partition by id, order by (select 1)) as [rank]
from @t
```

However, you will find the results are not in the original order and somewhat confusing:

```
id  rank
3   1
3   2
3   3
4   1
4   2
5   1
5   2
```

To preserve the original row order, you could build a temporary table or table variable with an `identity` column.  Select a `row_number()` partitioned by `id` from there:

```
declare @t table ([tkey] int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, [id] int)
insert into @t (id) values (4), (4), (5), (3), (5), (3), (3)

select
    [id],
    row_number() over (partition by [Id] order by [tkey]) as [rank]
from @t
order by [tkey]
```

Note that the final `order by [tkey]` really is necessary.  The query has the desired results:

```
id  rank
4   1
4   2
5   1
3   1
5   2
3   2
3   3
```

Here is a Common Table Expression (CTE) approach.  The CTE adds a `row_number()` to maintain the rows in the original order.  (This is the equivalent of the  `identity` column in the previous example.)  The actual ranking comes with the second `row_number()` when it does a `partition by id`.  This causes the 1st 4 gets 1, the 2nd 4 gets 2, etc.

The second `row_number()` must be ordered by the original order to rank correctly, but this is still not enough to preserve the order in the output.  A final `order by` ensures the ending order is the same.

```
declare @t table (id int)
insert into @t (id) values (4), (4), (5), (3), (5), (3), (3)

;with [tRows] (rownum, id) as
(
    select
        row_number() over (order by (select 1)) as [rownum],
        [id]
    from @t
)
select
    [id],
    row_number() over (partition by id order by [rownum]) as [rank]
from [tRows]
order by [rownum]
```

This query also has the desired results:

```
id  rank
4   1
4   2
5   1
3   1
5   2
3   2
3   3
```

In this example, you could use `rank()` instead of the second `row_number()`.  The difference between the functions is explained well in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747327/sql-rank-versus-row-number).  `rank()` would not work the same if, somehow, there were duplicate row numbers generated by the first `row_number()`, but that cannot happen.

Comment: Thank you so much Paul. I tried both row_number() and rank() but I messed up with the order by. So, I was not able to get the results.